# Append displayed as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to display each questions of `var Fake` after the user click the `#fab_send`. But the values of `var Fake` didn't displayed instead I received `undefined`.

Please help me, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function insertMessage() {
  msg = $('#chatSend').val();
  if ($.trim(msg) == '') {
    return false;
  }
  $('.chat_converse').append('<span class="chat_msg_item chat_msg_item_user"><p>' + msg + '</p></span>');
  $('#chatSend').val(null);
  setTimeout(function() {
    fakeMessage();
  }, 1000 + (Math.random() * 20) * 100);
   }
   
   $('#fab_send').click(function() {
  insertMessage();
   });
   
   $(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    insertMessage();
    return false;
  }
   })
   
   var Fake = [
  'What is your Account Number?',
  'What is your full name?',
  'What is your date of birth?',
  'What is your e-mail address?',
  'What is your mobile number?',
  'Type your concern'
   ]
   
   var i;
   function fakeMessage() {
  if ($('#chatSend').val() != '') {
    return false;
  }
  $('.chat_converse').append('<span class="chat_msg_item chat_msg_item_admin"><p></p></span>');
   
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('.chat_converse').append('<span class="chat_msg_item chat_msg_item_admin"><p>' + Fake[i] + '</p></span>');
    i++;
  }, 1000 + (Math.random() * 20) * 100);
   
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fabs">
  <div class="chat">
    <div id="chat_converse" class="chat_conversion chat_converse">
    </div>

    <div class="fab_field">
        <a id="fab_send" class="fab"><i class="zmdi zmdi-mail-send"></i></a>
        <textarea id="chatSend" name="chat_message" placeholder="Send a message" class="chat_field chat_message"></textarea>
    </div>
 </div>
    <a id="prime" class="fab"><i class="prime zmdi zmdi-comment-outline"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `i` is not assigned a value, if you want to increment it, you have start with `var i=0` etc.

Comment: @adeneo, it's now working but how can I call the ajax request function after the last question in `var Fake`?

Comment: Promises promises

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean?